# iBatis using a set for a resultMap as well as a parameterMap

Tags: java, ibatis

I want to pass a Set of Strings in an iBatis query for the parameter map as well as return a collection of strings for the result set.

Is this possible?

Example queries ...

```
SELECT * FROM some_table t WHERE t.some_column IN (values);

UPDATE some_table t SET t.some_column = 'some_value' WHERE t.other_column IN (values);
```

Walter

Comment: Can you clarify, perhaps an example ? What would the "set of strings" represent, what would they be mapped into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a List of Strings as one parameter, for example for building a `IN(val1,val2...)` query, then you should read about **dynamic** queries, in particular the [Iterate](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html) element. See [also](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=148958#postmenu_148958).

Answer (score 0):

For the return, In `SqlMapClientTemplate` there is the `queryForList` method.

As for the `Set` of `String` as parameter, I do not know if iBatis handles that; we built an object for that, and when I faced that problem it was in a sql `in` clause, so I made a loop with comma separated values.
Or you can convert the `Set` to an `HashMap` and pass that.