# Does Ibatis support Sets as parameter classes?

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

Does anyone know if Ibatis accepts Sets as parameter classes? I didn't see any docs on it, but when I did try it failed and told me it was looking for a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on usage. If you would like to iterate the elements of set for building `IN (...)` query, there is a way to do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729673/ibatis-using-a-set-for-a-resultmap-as-well-as-a-parametermap) with using `iterate` element.
If it doesnt work you might need to convert your Set to List and pass your variable as a list.

```
List list = new ArrayList(new HashSet());
```